# How to locate the index with in a nested list Python

Tags: python

from typing import List

```
def find_peak(m: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
    """
    Given an non-empty elevation map m, returns the cell of the
    highest point in m.

Examples (note some spacing has been added for human readablity)
>>> m = [[1,2,3],
         [9,8,7],
         [5,4,6]]
>>> find_peak(m)
[1,0]
>>> m = [[6,2,3],
         [1,8,7],
         [5,4,9]]
>>> find_peak(m)
[2,2]
"""
max_location = []
for sublist in m:
    max_location.append(max(sublist))
max_location = max(max_location)
for sublist in m:
    if max_location in sublist:
        return (m.index(max_location),sublist.index(max_location))
```

this doesnt really work since it just returns that number is not in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make good use of `enumerate`. First find the row (with its index) with the maximum number. Then find that number and its index in *that* row.

In both cases you need to provide a key to the `max` function so that it considers the value (not the index):

```
def find_peak(m):
    i, max_row = max(enumerate(m), key=lambda x: max(x[1]))
    j, max_val = max(enumerate(max_row), key=lambda x: x[1])
    return [i, j]
```

**Output**

```
print(find_peak([[1,2,3], [9,8,7], [5,4,6]]))
# [1, 0]
print(find_peak([[6,2,3], [1,8,7], [5,4,9]]))
# [2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum value in the flattened input structure, and then return the coordinates that specify the location of the maximum value previously found:

```
from typing import List
def find_peak(m: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
  _max = max([i for b in m for i in b])
  return [[i, a] for i in range(len(m)) for a in range(len(m[0])) if m[i][a] == _max][0]

print(list(map(find_peak, [[[1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7], [5, 4, 6]], [[6, 2, 3], [1, 8, 7], [5, 4, 9]]])))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: @BeierMu Glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier when you think about iterating over indices rather than the items on the list:

```
from itertools import product

d = [[1, 2, 3], [7, 9, 8], [4, 5, 6]]

# generate all indices
x_len = range(len(d))
y_len = range(len(d[0]))
indices = product(x_len, y_len)

# select maximal item by index
key = lambda x: d[x[0]][x[1]]
max_index = max(indices, key=key)

print(max_index)
```